User group membership defined in /etc/group is missing after login
I use Bookworm distro on RPI and without any reason stopped working applications which require gpio membership. Real groups membership for pi I get via
pi@digie35:~ $ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input render netdev lpadmin wireshark i2c spi

lists 17 group. Content of /etc/group (978bytes)
pi@digie35:~ $ cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:pi
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:pi
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:pi
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:pi
audio:x:29:pi,pulse
dip:x:30:
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
shadow:x:42:vnc
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:pi,vnc
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:pi
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:pi
users:x:100:pi
nogroup:x:65534:
systemd-journal:x:999:
systemd-network:x:998:
crontab:x:101:
input:x:102:pi
sgx:x:103:
kvm:x:104:
render:x:105:pi,vnc
netdev:x:106:pi
pi:x:1000:
systemd-timesync:x:997:
messagebus:x:107:
_ssh:x:108:
bluetooth:x:109:
avahi:x:110:
polkitd:x:996:
spi:x:995:pi
i2c:x:994:pi
gpio:x:993:pi
lightdm:x:111:
rtkit:x:112:
pipewire:x:113:
rdma:x:114:
lpadmin:x:115:pi
ssl-cert:x:116:
pulse:x:117:
pulse-access:x:118:
scanner:x:119:saned
saned:x:120:
colord:x:121:
sambashare:x:992:
vnc:x:991:
xrdp:x:122:
wireshark:x:123:pi

defines pi in 17 groups (18th is primary from /etc/passwd)
I get correct result from
pi@digie35:~ $ groups pi
pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input render netdev spi i2c gpio lpadmin wireshark

But login process somehow removes gpio froom list. I can use
pi@digie35:~ $ newgrp gpio

to add group. But when I do newgrp - then no progress. I see in strace that it read /etc/group 978bytes, and call get groups with list where is missing 993 (gpio).
read(4, "root:x:0:\ndaemon:x:1:\nbin:x:2:\ns"..., 4096) = 978
close(4)                                = 0
getgroups(16, 0x556e969ad0)             = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
getgroups(32, [4, 20, 24, 27, 29, 44, 46, 60, 100, 102, 105, 106, 115, 123, 994, 995, 1000]) = 17

Full strace:
pi@digie35:~ $ strace newgrp -
execve("/usr/bin/newgrp", ["newgrp", "-"], 0x7ffa933ba8 /* 47 vars */) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/suid-debug", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556e968000
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(2, F_GETFD)                       = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/suid-debug", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae1d6000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=95999, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 95999, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fae185000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=132984, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 327856, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae134000
mmap(0x7fae140000, 262320, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fae140000
munmap(0x7fae134000, 49152)             = 0
munmap(0x7fae181000, 12464)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fae15f000, 65536, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fae16f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7fae16f000
mmap(0x7fae171000, 61616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae171000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=198584, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 361080, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae0e7000
mmap(0x7fae0f0000, 295544, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fae0f0000
munmap(0x7fae0e7000, 36864)             = 0
munmap(0x7fae139000, 25208)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fae11e000, 69632, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fae12f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2f000) = 0x7fae12f000
mmap(0x7fae131000, 29304, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae131000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0000y\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1651408, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1826912, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fadf31000
mmap(0x7fadf40000, 1761376, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fadf40000
munmap(0x7fadf31000, 61440)             = 0
munmap(0x7fae0ef000, 96)                = 0
mprotect(0x7fae0c7000, 86016, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fae0dc000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18c000) = 0x7fae0dc000
mmap(0x7fae0e2000, 49248, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae0e2000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\267\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=67504, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 196672, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fadf0f000
mmap(0x7fadf10000, 131136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fadf10000
munmap(0x7fadf0f000, 4096)              = 0
munmap(0x7fadf31000, 57408)             = 0
mprotect(0x7fadf16000, 102400, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fadf2f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xf000) = 0x7fadf2f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fae1d4000
set_tid_address(0x7fae1d4510)           = 6321
set_robust_list(0x7fae1d4520, 24)       = 0
rseq(0x7fae1d4b60, 0x20, 0, 0xd428bc00) = 0
mprotect(0x7fae0dc000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fadf2f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fae12f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fae16f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x556cb8f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fae1db000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7fae185000, 95999)             = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/kernel/cap_last_cap", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstatfs(3, {f_type=PROC_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
read(3, "40\n", 7)                      = 3
close(3)                                = 0
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_CHOWN)       = 1
prctl(PR_GET_SECUREBITS)                = 0
prctl(PR_GET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 0, 0, 0, 0)  = 0
prctl(PR_CAP_AMBIENT, PR_CAP_AMBIENT_IS_SET, CAP_CHOWN, 0, 0) = 0
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_AUDIT) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getrandom("\xd1\xa1\xca\xe5\x6a\x9e\xd8\xd7", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x556e968000
brk(0x556e989000)                       = 0x556e989000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3048976, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3048976, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7fadc27000
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/loginuid", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "1000", 12)                     = 4
close(4)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(4, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 526
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1891, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1891
close(4)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1891, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1891
close(4)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=978, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "root:x:0:\ndaemon:x:1:\nbin:x:2:\ns"..., 4096) = 978
close(4)                                = 0
getgroups(16, 0x556e969ad0)             = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
getgroups(32, [4, 20, 24, 27, 29, 44, 46, 60, 100, 102, 105, 106, 115, 123, 994, 995, 1000]) = 17
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=978, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "root:x:0:\ndaemon:x:1:\nbin:x:2:\ns"..., 4096) = 978
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/gshadow", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/gshadow", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/login.defs", O_RDONLY) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12608, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(4, "#\n# /etc/login.defs - Configurat"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "ill allow other people to write "..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, " Use with caution - it is possib"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "                                "..., 4096) = 320
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/loginuid", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "1000", 12)                     = 4
close(4)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1891, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 1891
close(4)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {c_iflag=ICRNL|IXON|IUTF8, c_oflag=NL0|CR0|TAB0|BS0|VT0|FF0|OPOST|ONLCR, c_cflag=B38400|CS8|CREAD, c_lflag=ISIG|ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|IEXTEN|ECHOCTL|ECHOKE, ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {c_iflag=ICRNL|IXON|IUTF8, c_oflag=NL0|CR0|TAB0|BS0|VT0|FF0|OPOST|ONLCR, c_cflag=B38400|CS8|CREAD, c_lflag=ISIG|ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|IEXTEN|ECHOCTL|ECHOKE, ...}) = 0
newfstatat(0, "", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0xa), ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/10", 4095) = 11
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/pts/10", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0xa), ...}, 0) = 0
getpid()                                = 6321
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2301, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2301, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(4, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2301
lseek(4, -1461, SEEK_CUR)               = 840
read(4, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 1461
close(4)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
sendto(4, "<86>Oct  7 08:47:33 newgrp[6321]"..., 89, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 89
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[HUP], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[TSTP], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[TTIN], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[TTOU], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fae1d4510) = 6322
getgid()                                = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
newfstatat(5, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=978, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(5, "root:x:0:\ndaemon:x:1:\nbin:x:2:\ns"..., 4096) = 978
close(5)                                = 0

Also /etc/nsswitch.conf
pi@digie35:~ $ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.
passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis

I cannot
pi@digie35:~ $ strace newgrp gpio

connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
sendto(4, "<86>Oct  7 09:34:36 newgrp[6527]"..., 90, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 90
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[HUP], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[TSTP], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[TTIN], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[TTOU], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f99bd7510) = 6528
getgid()                                = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
newfstatat(5, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=978, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
setgroups: Operation not permitted
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_SETsetgid: Operation not permitted
)                   = 0
read(5, "root:x:0:\ndaemon:x:1:\nbin:x:2:\ns"..., 4096) = 978
close(5)                                = 0
wait4(6528, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], WSTOPPED, NULL) = 6528
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=6528, si_uid=1000, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
getpid()                                = 6527
sendto(4, "<86>Oct  7 09:34:36 newgrp[6527]"..., 88, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 88
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++

But it works
pi@digie35:~ $ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input render netdev lpadmin wireshark i2c spi
pi@digie35:~ $ newgrp gpio
pi@digie35:~ $ groups
gpio adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input render netdev lpadmin wireshark i2c spi pi

Any idea why group gpio is excluded from secondary group membership for user pi ?

Are you using NFS at all?

Do you mean Network File System? No. Is it relevant ?

Yes, some uses of NFS limit the number of groups to 16. Apart from that there shouldn’t be any realistic limits but your question shows that that’s not the case.

Could there be any non-printing characters in /etc/group or other files?  Can you use sg with useful effect (you might need to assign a password with gpasswd first)?  If you remove membership from one of the other groups, does this change things?

@BobGoddard strace implicitly removes setuid.  This also explains the lack of shadow file access, and newgrp not finishing properly.

I do not think there is an unprintable character. Meanwhile after several reboots (I swapping twice between Wayland and X11) it starts working and I see all pi's groups. Maybe there was temporarily something limiting it to 16 as mentioned @StephenKitt. Strange gpio is not in extreme position of list.

Is it possible that the memberships in /etc/group don't match /etc/gshadow?

I think there were consistent data in /etc/passwd+shadow+group+gshadow. strace considers /etc/gshadow in next step (after refused gpio group from list) with result Permission denied
